# Why was Lasky on board the Nimitz?

Tags: the-final-countdown

The 1980 film *The Final Countdown* was a time travel story where the USS *Nimitz* aircraft carrier was transported back to and then returns from December, 1941, just prior to and during the initiation of the Japanese attack on Pearl Harbor.

One of those on board was a civilian Mr. Lasky, who was sent to observe the ship by his employer, a reclusive and unseen Mr. Tideman whose company had a role in constructing the *Nimitz*. Departure of the *Nimitz* from port had been held up (for days?) awaiting Lasky's arrival.

During the time travel adventure, Lasky plays the role of semi-advisor to the ship's captain and other officers; but he doesn't actually know why he's on board (or only has at least a vague idea to act as an efficiency analyst). In most cases when asked for advice, he either doesn't seem to know or just guesses the same as the rest of them.

Eventually when the *Nimitz* returns to port, back in 1980, Lasky disembarks and

> discovers that his boss, Tideman,  was actually an officer of the *Nimitz* who had been stranded back in 1941. Tideman had apparently used his knowledge of future events to enrich himself, build the *Nimitz*, and ultimately have Lasky on board for the critical events.

But what was the actual purpose for Lasky to be on board? Why was it so essential?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the following might be at least a few reasons Mr. Tideman would want to send Mr. Lasky back in time if he believed it was necessary to maintain the timeline continuity.

1. It was Mr. Lasky who was the first to observe that the recon photos taken by the overflight of Pearl Harbor matched those of the historical photos in Commander Owen's cabin.That along with the other information helped convince the captain played by Kirk Douglas that the Nimitz had indeed traveled back in time.
2. Mr. Lasky also highlighted the fact that it was Senator Chapman whom the Nimitz crew rescued from the Zero attack.  Senator Chapman was the vice chairman of the armed services defense committee.  History recorded him as being missing and presumed dead. Mr. Lasky pointed out that Senator Chapman was a strong advocate of the theory that Japan could be an aggressor against the U.S. in the Pacific.

While events may have continued mostly the same without these actions, Mr. Tideman may not have been sure. Thus, wanted to take every opportunity to preserve the timeline to the best he could.

That leads to a possible reason 3 which may be more the most important in terms of continuity.

3. By Mr. Tideman requiring to have Mr. Lasky be on board, it delayed the launch of the Nimitz by two days.  If it had launched earlier perhaps Mr. Tideman thought the Nimitz would not get caught in the anomaly. Thus the time loop would collapse.

Comment: While not quite agreeing with everything in #3, I would also add, BECAUSE when he got stuck in the past, Mr Lasky was on the Nimitz. So when the time came for the Nimitz to get underway he KNEW Mr Lasky had to be on board so arranged for him to be on it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as we know there is no time travel. But time travel and the resulting paradoxes have been a trope in science fiction for a long time.

It seems consistent with the movie that Tideman deliberately attempted to create a [stable time loop](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/main/stabletimeloop). Tideman remembered Lasky being on the *Nimitz*, so he made sure that the initial situation was set up exactly as he remembered it because he had no idea what would happen if he didn't do that.

Comment: I don't see how your first paragraph is useful.

Comment: @Acccumulation, if Tideman *deliberately* created a time loop, he must have known the concept. Perhaps not the name, but "all will be well if I set things to happen as I remember them."